# Removing values from lists using comparisons (Python3)

Tags: list, comparison, python-3.9

I'm using Python3.

I have 2 lists for this example:

`G1 = [0, 5, 10, 18, 24, 31, 40]`

`G2 = [0, 8, 15, 28, 37, 50, 61]`

Is it possible to get Python to take the **last** element in a list (in *G1* this is 40), and then remove every element from *G2* whose value is < 40?

The end goal would be for *G2* to read:
`[50, 61]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use list comprehension:

```
G1 = [0, 5, 10, 18, 24, 31, 40]
G2 = [0, 8, 15, 28, 37, 50, 61]

G2 = [v for v in G2 if v >= G1[-1]]
print(G2)
```

Prints:

```
[50, 61]
```

Answer (score 0):

G1 = [0, 5, 10, 18, 24, 31, 40]
G2 = [0, 8, 15, 28, 37, 50, 61]

print(G1[6])
print(G1[-1])

a=[]
for v in G2:
if v >= 40:
a.append(v)

print(a)